# Custom overrides the Enabled property of the UserControl?

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, controls

I have user_control with 1 textbox and a button. I want to override the Enabled property of the control in such a way, retain the button always enabled and enable / disable of the control only affect the textbox.

How can i archive it?
Thanks in advance.

Edited : I think my question may not be clear. Actually I have overrides the Enabled property as follows,

```
Private m_Enabled As Boolean
Public Overloads Property Enabled() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_Enabled
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        Button1.Enabled = True
        TextBox1.Enabled = value
        m_Enabled = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I have place this usercontrol and few other textboxs in a Panel1. I try to loop through the controls one by one and disable it.

```
    For Each panelControl As Control In Panel1.Controls
        panelControl.Enabled = False
    Next panelControl
```

This enabled property never called in this case. (whole control get disabled / enabled)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Be *very* careful with `Overloads` in cases like this.  All it does it suppress a warning from the compiler that tells you that you are probably doing it wrong.  The Enabled property is not virtual so you cannot override it.  You are actually creating *another* property with the same name.  Your loop doesn't use it.  You are much better off creating another property that's named, say, TextBoxEnabled.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your cast: `For Each panelControl As Control` which will use the control's enabled property, not your overload.

Try casting instead:

```
For Each ctrl As UserControl1 In Panel2.Controls.OfType(Of UserControl1)()
  ctrl.Enabled = False
Next
```